# Need to unwrap Int?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this error message: Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Int'

with this code:

```
let data = document.data()

let uid = data["userid"] as? String ?? ""
let location = data["location"] as? String ?? ""
let currentRating = data["currentRating"] as? Int
let usualRating = data["usualRating"] as? Int


var Submission = RatingSubmission(uid: uid, location: location, currentRating: currentRating, usualRating: usualRating)
```

what do I need to add to currentRating and usualRating in the Submission variable so that it runs properly?

Comment: You can use `if let`, `if let currentRating = data["currentRating"] as? Int, let usualRating = data["usualRating"] as? Int {`

Comment: The answer is in the string variables: if the data is not an `Int`, what shall the code return? `let currentRating = data["currentRating"] as? Int ?? 0`

Comment: It depends on what is going to happen if the value is `nil`. **You** are the owner of the database. **You** know if all fields have values. You can assign a default value, force unwrap all fields or use Optional Binding.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that RatingSubmission function works with Int values but you if you assign them as optional values there is a chance to these variables may be "nill". To avoid this you can either remove this option like this:

```
let currentRating = data["currentRating"] as? Int ?? 0
let usualRating = data["usualRating"] as? Int ?? 0
```

Second option, if you sure these values are not nill, you can downcasting using "as!".(this is not safe most time)

```
let currentRating = data["currentRating"] as! Int
let usualRating = data["usualRating"] as! Int
```

Third option, you can check the values with if let;

```
let currentRating = data["currentRating"] as? Int
let usualRating = data["usualRating"] as? Int
if let currentRating = Int(data["currentRating"]), let usualRating = Int(data["usualRating"]) {
var Submission = RatingSubmission(uid: uid, location: location, currentRating: currentRating, usualRating: usualRating)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `get()` method on the document which was made specifically for getting properties from documents.

```
if let usualRating = document.get("usualRating") as? Int {
    print(usualRating)
}
```

Alternatively, you can one-line it by giving it a default value (of `0` in this case). But this would appear like an anti-pattern to me just on the face of it.

```
let usualRating = document.get("usualRating") as? Int ?? 0
```